# Tomee Installation process?

Tags: java, apache-tomee, openejb, tomee-7

SPEC : jdk1.8 ,TOMEE702, win10

Question : How/What/which to install and use TOMEE for open-ejb3.X ?

url : http://tomee.apache.org/download-ng.html

I could not find any easy install-able for all of the downloads from the url.

with regards
Karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to install

Just unzip the archive you downloaded.

> which distribution

TomEE comes in several flavors which offer either alternative implementations for some of the specifications and/or additional functionality. Without more concrete requirements it's not possible recommend concrete flavor.

You can see the comparison here: http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html Note that the table is for version 1.7 For 7.0.x, the details are in the text below.
The difference between plume/plus is that the first one uses eclipselink and mojara, while "plus" uses openjpa and myfaces.

The difference between web-profile and the others interms of ejb is that web-profile by spec supports ejb-lite, while plus/plume should support ejb full.

Also I'd recommend you to use the latest and greates version of tomee - currently 7.0.3 and upgrade to 7.0.4 as soon as it's released as it contains A LOT of fixes.

Comment: Thx  for quick reply , URL http://tomee.apache.org/manual-installation.html seems to be outdated in version details.My concern was to use TOMEE with Open-EJB for ear based deployments with JNDI to MQ/DB/File system.Is there any URL with updated TOMEE for 702 version ?

Comment: @N.S.Karthik Hi, that link is indeed outdated and for the war drop-in which requires some manual steps. You'd better use plus/plume instead, where all integration steps were already done by the tomee team.  Then you'll just need to unzip it, and start it like tomcat with `catalina.sh run`

Comment: Thx for the same, So with Plus/Plum (I did not see any open-ejb folders within )...I can use ejb's in ears developed  and can it also support  a Non HTTP  channels as ejb's do provide support for RMI clients ?

Comment: I think it should work. The integration with tomcat should not limit openejb itself. You ma be interested in http://tomee.apache.org/ejb-refs.html and http://openejb.apache.org/clients.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know the way of using openejb with tomcat server.
To do that you will have to download openejb.war file.

http://tomee.apache.org/download/apache-openejb-3.1.4.html

After downloading openejb.war file download the tomcat server which can be downloaded from the link given below.

http://tomcat.apache.org/

Extract your tomcat zip file to a folder and deploy openejb.war file to tomcat's webapp folder.

If you are using Eclipse as an IDE then setup a tomcat server by going to window menu -> preferences -> server -> Runtime Environments. Add your version of tomcat server.

After adding the server, check the Project Explorer view, there you should see Servers folder. Finally right click on the project explorer view, select import and search for war file and lastly add the openejb.war file.

If everything goes well you should have successfully added openejb to your tomcat server.
If you have an openejb based project then you can add it by going to window menu -> show view and search for server. You should probably see the server view at the very end of your eclipse window. Right click on it and select Add and Remove. In the Add and Remove window you can control your projects deployment.

If you don't have a project then develop a project and add it to your server and run the tomcat server. You might also need to configure openejb.xml file depending upon your needs.

Comment: Thx for the reply ,http://tomee.apache.org/manual-installation.html seems to be outdate with Open-ejb & TOMEE deployement  as per the avaliable dwnloads in http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html, My concern is to start with basic open-ejb supporting "ear" to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Tomee installation is no different then any other Tomcat installation. You should download the compressed file and extract it into your desired directory, preferably into root drive in case of windows extract it into the c drive.

Once extracted you can start it from the bin folder `startup.bat` or `startup.sh` script. Make sure you have the compatible jdk installed into your system and the path is configured for the JDK.

You can find the detailed installation step from the [official documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/installing-tomee.html) of apache.

Comment: Thx for the Reply, But I need to deploy ear's and support the same with JNDI (MQ/DB/File)... this is not in line with Tomcat which usally supports war format. Alos the Official Document at http://tomee.apache.org/manual-installation.html  is outdated of version details..and confusing